# Extracting time series trend analysis parameters from kriging using ArcGIS (versus R)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, parameters, kriging, time-series, geostatistical-analyst

A grad student has asked me a question about extracting trend parameters for a time series of data using ordinary kriging ArcGIS tools. I'm not an expert in the spatial statistics options of ArcGIS, so I'm hoping to find some advice here. Currently the student has decided to stick with R due to frustration with not being able to figure out the same process in ArcGIS, but it would still be helpful to know if it's even possible in ArcGIS. They say:

> We are having trouble figuring out how to extract the trend
> parameters, more specifically the equation of the line that was used
> to remove the trend from the data, to which the kriging model is
> fitting. The equation is essential when I present my thesis so that I
> can say with confidence why I chose one model over the other. We know
> there is a goodness of fit parameter, but we want to have a better
> indication of the best model to choose rather than just the goodness
> of fit. We know that we can extract out the trend parameters in R, but
> we have not been able to figure it out in ArcGIS.
>
> Do you happen to know how to extract the trend parameters from the
> Geostatistical Analyst tool?

Answer (score 1):

I'd encourage your student to thoroughly read over the [ArcGIS documentation on kriging](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/geostatistical-analyst/kriging-in-geostatistical-analyst.htm). If what they are looking for still seems like a possible output of the ArcGIS Geostatistical Wizard but they can't figure out where to find the output, then I would encourage them to post a detailed question here on GIS SE or on [GeoNet](https://community.esri.com/). Their question should explain what they've tried so far (i.e. detailed step by step working through the Geostatistical Wizard, with references to documentation as needed) and where they are still getting stuck.